# Can I add another cable to a box with four cables in it?

Tags: electrical

I would like to add an outlet in my home. I was going to do it the typical way and add a new neutral and load to an existing outlet.  Run the wire to a new location and add a j-box.

The issue is the closest outlet already has 4 wires coming into it.

Can I still add the outlet by taking off of the existing outlet?

Comment: What is the size of the source box, where the "closest outlet" is?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the box you're planning to tap off of, what size is it, where is it, and where are you putting the outlet?

Comment: It is standard 15amp 125v outlet. I would like to add a outlet higher up on the wall for the tv.

Comment: @Marc -- it's on a general lighting/receptacle circuit right?

Comment: Yes it is a general circuit

Comment: I edited your title into an actual question. Feel free to modify it if that isn't what you're asking. First maybe edit the post body to be more clear. Are you asking about cable capacity for the box, or connectivity to the wires and outlet?

Answer (score 1):

This is in conjunction to Harpers answer. I'm not sure but this might be what you are looking for:
[image]

FYI the pigtail method is now required by the NEC. Try article 300.13(B). Device Removal.

When you do pigtail it make sure you have the correct size wire nut.

Comment: The pigtail requirement is only for the neutral, oddly enough and only for MWBC's

Comment: @Kris -- it's not odd when you think of what opening the neutral on a MWBC does to the voltages present there...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that makes good sense.  I totally didn't catch that it would become a series circuit.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how do you attach the two extra wires when all the screws on the receptacle are in use?  The question right before yours wanted to know the *same exact thing* and I wrote an answer here.
https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/113980/47125